# Install Vimba python on Windows

Tags: python, github, installation, sh, vimba-sdk

I am not very familiar with programming on Windows yet. With my code I want to control a camera, for this I wanted to use the Vimba Python interface. Thus I downloaded the GitHub repository of AlliedVision.
Now my question: In the folder is an ***Install.sh*** - file, which I know otherwise only from Linux/Ubuntu. How can I execute this file or is there another way to install this repository from Vimba on my PC?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the whole Vimba SDK and install the exe, Vimba Python is already included. This is also mentioned on the VimbaPython Github page. The documentation will be installed together with the APIs, in the install directory.

https://www.alliedvision.com/en/products/vimba-sdk/

If you are using Alvium cameras, I would recommend the newer VimbaX API and VmbPy wrapper.

https://www.alliedvision.com/en/products/software/vimba-x-sdk/

Vimba Python is just a wrapper for the underlying C API, so it can't be used on its own.